# curl stops downloading using multiple connections on Linux

Tags: c++, linux, curl, download, multiprocessing

I have a problem using curl,from version 1.28.1 to 1.37.1 - same problem occurs:
In Linux environment, using the command line, I am running the following commands simultaneously:

```
curl -o /dev/null "http://example.com/short_video.mp4" -o /dev/null "http://example.com/short_video.mp4" &
curl -o /dev/null "http://example.com/short_video.mp4" &
curl -o /dev/null "http://example.com/short_video.mp4" &
curl -o /dev/null "http://example.com/short_video.mp4" &
```

The problem is - it starts downloading successfully, but often, on a high speed internet connection, one of the downloads get stuck on a zero speed, and the whole process gets stuck..
the only thing that helps is using the speed limit:

```
curl --speed-limit 5 -o /dev/null "http://example.com/short_video.mp4" &
```

and then it recognizes that the speed is low and kills the download, but I want to know how to avoid this situation in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a small research, it seemed it just sometimes happnes to any single connection, (Even without the use of multiple connections)
It seems like a bug in TCP Flow Control refereed to as: Silly window syndrome:
 https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Silly_window_syndrome

Quote:

> A serious problem can arise in the sliding window operation when the
>   sending application program creates data slowly, the receiving
>   application program consumes data slowly, or both. If a server with
>   this problem is unable to process all incoming data, it requests that
>   its clients reduce the amount of data they send at a time (the window
>   setting on a TCP packet). If the server continues to be unable to
>   process all incoming data, the window becomes smaller and smaller,
>   sometimes to the point that the data transmitted is smaller than the
>   packet header, making data transmission extremely inefficient.

I noticed that after a long time (2 minutes or more) it starts downloading again.